# php set input "name" to php echo variable

Tags: php, html

I have a form with two radio buttons as "yes" and "No"

I m bringing the "name" of the input from PHP variable I get from the DB.

But however, it echoes in the form but when submitting gives the error.

**My HTML code goes as:**

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">
<?php 
    $sql6 = "SELECT * FROM subadminpriv WHERE subadmin_id = '$sa_id'";
    $result6 = $conn->query($sql6);
    if ($result6->num_rows > 0) {                               
    while($row6 = $result6->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $sa_id = $row6["subadmin_id"];
    $privilege = $row6["privilege"];
    $status = $row6["status"];
?>
     <div class="togglebutton m-t-30" >
         <label >
            <strong>&#8658; <?php echo $privilege; ?> </strong> <br>
            <input name="<?php echo $privilege; ?>" value="1" type="radio">Yes 
            <input name="<?php echo $privilege; ?>" value="0" type="radio">No
        </label>
     </div>
    <hr>
<?php } }else { } ?>
<button class="btn button" type="submit">Assign Privileges</button>
</form>
```

Where the $privilege is "Can See Vendors"

So in here, I'm trying to get the fields "sa_id, privilege, status" from the DB and echo as many radio(yes/no) as the fields in DB.

It works, however, and I echoed the "name" field in the input with PHP variable when I inspect it, it gives the value form the DB, but when I submit and echo it, it gives an error.

**The PHP phpfile.php page goes as :**

```
<?php include ('../db.php'); ?>
<?php

$priv1 = $_POST['privilege1'];

echo $priv1;
?>
```

Here "privilege1" is the actual privilege name from the DB field.

while it gives error as `"Notice: Undefined index: privilege1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\blah blah blah/pIpfile.php on line 6"`

While I Was expecting value I given to radio button like 1 or 0;

Hope i m Clear with my problem. Any Help is Appreciated...

Comment: Does F12 in Chrome show that 'privilege1' is part of the form data sent to the server?  Also check for typos and different capitalization, PRIV != priv != Priv

Comment: When you are calling the name field from database is there any space after or before the name field. In that case you can use `trim($privilege)`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how I missed it.

The name in the input field won't accept space, so I changed it to "Can_See_Vendors"

**Solved**